# Javascript: Skipping every 4th item in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I have an array full of pixel color values ordered sequentially (R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A...etc.) and I'm trying to move through them changing the values for R, G, and B, but I want to leave A alone. What's the best way to specifically skip the 4th (or n-th) value of an array?

What I'm trying to do:

- With every frame, increase the first R value (1st item in the array) by 1.
- Go from 0 to 255 in the R value.
- When R = 255, reset it to 0 and increase the G value (2nd item in the array) by 1.
- R continues to cycle, going from 0 to 255 and increasing G each time until:
- When G = 255, reset it to 0 and increase the B value (3rd item) by 1.
- Same thing, G cycles increasing B by one each time.
- When B = 255, reset it to 0 and **skip** the A value (4th item!) and instead increase the  next R value, the 5th item. And then continue this ad infinitum until the end of the array.

The project I'm working on is in P5.js but I figured that this problem is more specific to Javascript.

Thanks everyone!

ETA: Since people were asking what I was using here you go:

```
var m = 0;
var array = [0];

function draw() {
  var last = array[array.length-1];

  loadPixels();
  pixels[array[last]] += 1;
  updatePixels();

  if (pixels[array[last]] == 255) {
    loadPixels();
    pixels[array[last]] = 0;
    updatePixels();
    m += 1;
    array.push(m);
  }
}
```

This seems to work close to fine, and I can watch the pixels cycle through colors, but then they quickly turn white (likely because the `if` statement is resetting the A value to zero after it loops through it. Although I'd still like it to keep all pixels moving (kinda like how I described in the list) instead of just doing one and then moving on to the next.

I originally didn't include this because I'm still super new to Javascript and realize my work thus far is likely so esoterically bootstrapped that I fear most won't be able to make heads or tails of it. But if you can, all the better I suppose.

Comment: Can you provide some data and code?

Comment: What's that array for, can you post an example? How many of tham you have in array, how are they related?

Comment: Use modulo division, perhaps?

Comment: Is there something else being done at each increment?

Comment: @incutonez *modulo ""division""* can be also a bit more descriptive ;)

Comment: I didn't include the code I was using because it's pretty P5.js specific, but I'll edit to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very concisely using modulo arithmetic:

```js
var myPixels = [255, 255, 255, 0.5, 255, 189, 22, 0.3];

function updatePixels(pixels) {
    var shouldContinue = true,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; i < pixels.length && shouldContinue; i += 1) {
        // Skip every 4th index
        if (i % 4 !== 3) {
            pixels[i] = (pixels[i] + 1) % 256;

            // keep going as long as the current RGB value has just been reset to 0
            shouldContinue = (pixels[i] === 0);
        }
    }
}

// EXAMPLE USAGE    
console.log(myPixels);
updatePixels(myPixels);
console.log(myPixels);
updatePixels(myPixels);
console.log(myPixels);
```

When run, this produces the output:

```
[255, 255, 255, 0.5, 0, 189, 22, 0.3]
[0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 190, 22, 0.3]
[1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 190, 22, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the best way to specifically skip the 4th (or n-th) value of an array?

The idea is to create a `for` loop with `i` as the index and check if `i % 4 != 3` is true. The below code will skip 4n-th items of the array, where `n` is a positive integer.

```
var arr = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'R', 'G', 
           'B', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'A','R'];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 3) {
        alert(arr[i]); // will display only R, G, and B

        // do your thing here for R, G, and B
    }
}
```

The string elements are just for an example. You can change `arr` with an array of numbers and use the same `for` loop.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o7epn1cb/

Answer (score 1):

Skip a iteration with keyword `continue`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    if(i % 4 === 3) {
        continue; // this keyword means skip following steps, jump to next iteration
    }
    // work to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

skip by 4 on the array loop logic, and then three nested loops on the RGB to do what you want, see below:

p.s. since my answer got incorrectly voted down, i added a sample array and a console.log message, to give you a full working sample that you can run in node or a browser to see it doing exactly what the OP asked for.

```html
var a=[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4];
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=4) // notice the i+=4 instead of i++, this the trick.
    {
      for(b=0;b<256;b++) {
        for(g=0;g<256;g++) {
          for(r=0;r<256;r++) {
            a[i]=r; // R cycles from 0 to 255 
            console.log(i, a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]);
          }
          a[i+1]=g; // G cycles from 0 to 255
        }
        a[i+2]=b; // B cycles from 0 to 255
      }
    }
```

Comment: All this will accomplish is setting all of the RGB values to 255 in an extremely inefficient fashion.

Comment: no it does not, run it in your browser, or in node, and you will see that it does exactly what the OP asked for. p.s. i had initially a typo in the for loops, in the b++ and r++, i just fixed the typo, but the logic remains. i can also post a working example with a sample array if you wish.

Comment: By all means, please post a sample.

Comment: No, this isn't what OP was describing. When the loops are done running, the array will contain [255,255,255,1,255,255,255,2,255,255,255,3,255,255,255,4] and the initial values will not have mattered at all.